# Launching Libgdx project to IPhonesimulator

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

Im trying to make sure my app works on IOS. And doing so by trying to launch it to a IPhonesimulator on my mac.

doing:

```
./gradlew ios:launchIPhoneSimulator
```

Makes my app start on the simulator, the standard splashscreen by libgdx appears and then it shuts down and nothing more happends.

But when I build it `./gradlew ios:build ios:launchIPhoneSimulator` I get these errors:

> 2015-06-12 17:39:36.226 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSApplication: iOS version: 8.3
>   2015-06-12 17:39:36.227 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSApplication: Running in 64-bit mode
>   2015-06-12 17:39:36.229 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSApplication: scale: 2.0
>   2015-06-12 17:39:36.347 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSApplication: Unscaled View: Portrait 375x667
>   2015-06-12 17:39:36.347 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSApplication: View: Portrait 750x1334
>   2015-06-12 17:39:36.348 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSGraphics: 750.0x1334.0, 2.0
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.104 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSGraphics: Display: ppi=264, density=1.65
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.631 IOSLauncher[730:16658] 17:39:37.614 ERROR:     98: Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.631 IOSLauncher[730:16658] 17:39:37.631 ERROR:     100: Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.632 IOSLauncher[730:16658] 17:39:37.632 WARNING:   230: The input device is 0x0; '(null)'
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.632 IOSLauncher[730:16658] 17:39:37.632 WARNING:   234: The output device is 0x26; 'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.632 IOSLauncher[730:16658] 17:39:37.632 ERROR:     296: error '!obj'
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.632 IOSLauncher[730:16618] 17:39:37.632 ERROR:     296: error -66680
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.633 IOSLauncher[730:16518] 17:39:37.632 ERROR:     >aurioc> 806: failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16, inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, inter>)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.633 IOSLauncher[730:16618] 17:39:37.633 ERROR:     113: * * * NULL AQIONode object
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.633 IOSLauncher[730:16518] OAL Error: +[ALWrapper openDevice:]: Could not open device (null)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.633 IOSLauncher[730:16518] OAL Error: -[ALDevice initWithDeviceSpecifier:]: : Failed to create OpenAL device (null)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.635 IOSLauncher[730:16518] OAL Error: +[ALWrapper closeDevice:]: Invalid Value (error code 0x0000a004)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.635 IOSLauncher[730:16618] 17:39:37.635 ERROR:     703: Can't make UISound Renderer
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.636 IOSLauncher[730:16518] OAL Warning: -[OALAudioSession onAudioError:]: Received audio error notification, but last reset was 0.377221 seconds ago. Doing nothing.
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.636 IOSLauncher[730:16518] OAL Error: -[OALSimpleAudio initWithSources:]: : Could not create OpenAL device
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.656 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [error] IOSAudio: No OALSimpleAudio instance available, audio will not be availabe
>   2015-06-12 17:39:37.944 IOSLauncher[730:16518] [debug] IOSApplication: created
>   2015-06-12 17:39:39.155 IOSLauncher[730:16658] 17:39:39.155 ERROR:     296: error -66680
>   2015-06-12 17:39:39.156 IOSLauncher[730:16664] 17:39:39.156 ERROR:     >aurioc> 806: failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16, inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, inter>)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:39.157 IOSLauncher[730:16664] OAL Error: +[ALWrapper openDevice:]: Could not open device (null)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:39.157 IOSLauncher[730:16664] OAL Error: -[ALDevice initWithDeviceSpecifier:]: : Failed to create OpenAL device (null)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:39.157 IOSLauncher[730:16664] OAL Error: +[ALWrapper closeDevice:]: Invalid Value (error code 0x0000a004)
>   2015-06-12 17:39:39.157 IOSLauncher[730:16664] OAL Warning: -[OALAudioSession onAudioError:]: Received audio error notification. Resetting audio session.
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL

And here´s my IOSLauncher if its to any help..

```
public class IOSLauncher extends IOSApplication.Delegate {

@Override
protected IOSApplication createApplication() {
    IOSApplicationConfiguration config = new IOSApplicationConfiguration();
    return new IOSApplication(new MainClass(null,null), config);
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    NSAutoreleasePool pool = new NSAutoreleasePool();
    UIApplication.main(argv, null, IOSLauncher.class);
    pool.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Do you have the latest XCode installed?

Comment: Yes I think so, 6.3.1 I got.

Comment: Have you tried to launch through the IDE instead? You can get better logging that way, especially if you can click the project and Run As -> iOS Simulator App. Also you should not need the `ios:build` command.  Finally, does the program work for the other platforms?

Comment: Make sure you create a blank Xcode project and run it on a device or simulator first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simulator's audio output is borked. The openal audio toolkit is failing init which is causing everything to crash.

Comment: OK, but why does it happen and what should I do about it? Is this in no way caused by my code?

Comment: When I had this happen to me, it was caused by my OSX host losing audio output after an update. I got my OSX host working with audio again and the issue with no audio in the simulator was resolved. Is your OSX host doing audio fine?

Comment: Actually no, it isn't, but it is strange that I only get the error intermittently(?)

Comment: Yes, it does seem strange if it is intermittent, one would think it would be consistent, but I was using Mavericks at the time. My only suggestion is to get the audio on the OS-X host working and see if that helps.